# Is this normal or due to bug in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, xen

I am new to mongodb and i installed it on **xen para virtual vm** and when given command

**"mongo"** terminal freezed and on the **top** output command mongo is taking almost **100% CPU**.

Is this a bug,or does the mongo command made the scheduler to consider the process **interactive** and resulted in more cpu usage?

**Running Mongo 2.0.4,Ubuntu 12.04, kernel-3.2.0-23-generic as VM**

Comment: I don't know about xen para however I would definitely say the terminal freezing and taking nearly 100% CPU is almost certainly a bug, you must find posting this on mongodb-user helpful too :)

Comment: mongo is the client that connects to mongod - is mongod running? Did you build mongo or did you use precompiled binaries? It sounds like it might be an architecture issue.

Comment: 100% CPU usage for the `mongo` shell is definitely not normal.  Is anything else actively using your MongoDB instance, or is this from a fresh install?  If you are just getting started I would suggest using MongoDB 2.2 instead, and installing using the binary packages provided by 10gen: [Ubuntu installation instructions](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/).

Comment: @snez Mongo installation was through apt-get,and mongodb is running ok .each time when i give "mongo" command another process spawns taking CPU :-(.it got fixed when upgraded from 2.0.4 to 2.2.2.Thanx :-)

Comment: @Stennie that was a fresh installation and nothing was using mongo.It got fixed when upgraded to 2.2.2.So seems like a bug with older version.

Comment: Good to hear it was fixed by installing the current version; sounds like there was something amiss with the original install ;-)